# Photon lines along path - Error dimension to large

Tags: paths, tikz-feynman

I am trying to produce a photon line along a fancy path. I have managed the following figure:

[image]

using the code:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,angles,quotes,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm,
    photon/.style={decorate,decoration={snake,post length=2mm,pre length=2mm, segment length=1.0mm, amplitude=0.5mm,}}
    ]

        \draw [<->,>=stealth',black,photon] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (0.5,0.5) (3,0)};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Strangely when I simply replace the plot line using different coordinates, such as

```
\draw [<->,>=stealth',black,photon] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (1,-1) (2,-1) (3,0)};
```

I get an error

> Dimensions too large.

pointing to that line.

I can only, guess, maybe this is because the photon wiggles and the curvature give weird dimensions together. Any suggestions how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem with decorations. According to my experience the chances of getting `dimension too large` errors decreases substantially when using the `hobby` library to draw the smooth curves.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,hobby}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm,
    photon/.style={decorate,decoration={snake,post length=2mm,pre length=2mm, segment length=1.0mm, amplitude=0.5mm,}}
    ]

    \draw [<->,>=stealth',black,photon, use Hobby shortcut] 
        (0,0) .. (1,-1) .. (2,-1) .. (3,0);

    %    \draw [<->,>=stealth',black,photon] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (0.5,0.5) (3,0)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The path looks usually somewhat different from what one obtains with `plot[smooth] {<coordinates>}` but it is a valid smooth interpolation (and in some sense even a nicer one).

Comment: Why should `dimension too large` error appear if there are no excess dimensions? Thanks!

Comment: @manooooh The curvatures become too large. *In principle* this is a fixable problem. However, decorations are reasonably fast because they work with TeX dimensions. If you were to replace the computations by `fpu` stuff (or `xfp` for that matter), they would become significantly slower. But I would agree that one should be able to switch on `fpu`. Yet implementing this will be enormous efforts.